# How to get the MapOptions object from a map with Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In Google Maps api v2 you could get parameters such as the map type, zoom etc directly from the map object. In version 3 you have the setOptions method to set some parameters, but there is no getOptions() or options to retrieve them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access those properties via methods on the [Map](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) class:

- getZoom()
- [getMapTypeId](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapTypeId)()
- getCenter()
- etc..

Comment: Yep that's the only way... Btw, it's a pity that the v3 API reference does not have an anchor link for each method, as the v2 API reference has.

Comment: @daniel-vassallo Heh .. I agree, I was a bit thrown when I discovered I couldn't link to the each one ;)

Comment: Is maxZoom accessible? I don't see any getMaxZoom().

Comment: If you inspect the Map object there is a getOptions() prototype, however it appears to not be reliable.

Comment: Seems like there are not any methods to get these :(
var mapOptions = {
     zoomControl: false,
     scrollwheel: false,
     navigationControl: false,
     draggable: false,
     disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
 };

Answer (score 4):

You can also access options using the `get` method on the map as an [`MVCObject`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#MVCObject) as shown in this example

```js
// create map
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151);
var myOptions = {
  center: myLatlng,
  zoom: 5
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

map.setOptions({
  streetViewControl: false,
  zoom: 6,
  zoomControl: false,
  }
);

document.getElementById("center").value = map.get('center');
document.getElementById("streetViewControl").value = map.get('streetViewControl');
document.getElementById("zoom").value = map.get('zoom');
document.getElementById("zoomControl").value = map.get('zoomControl');
```

```css
#map_canvas {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}

input {
  width: 90px;
  }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>

<input type="text" id="center" /> center<br>
<input type="text" id="streetViewControl" /> streetViewControl<br>
<input type="text" id="zoom" /> zoom<br>
<input type="text" id="zoomControl" /> zoomControl<br>
...
```