# How to set google.maps.Map options while preserving the previous settings?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a system using google maps api v3, the system is quite big with various javascript modules that I load. Now I found a tricky thing: if I set the map options with setOptions, previous setting is deleted:

I.e., if one of my modules needs to change the position of the map selector:

```
my_map.setOptions({ mapTypeControlOptions: 
      { position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT }
});
```

it will reset settings of another module, which is adding new map types!! :

```
my_map.setOptions({ mapTypeControlOptions: {
                            mapTypeIds: [
                                    google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                                    google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
                                    google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
                                    google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
                                    'OSM',
                                    'OCM'
                            ]
})
```

I was thinking of a workaround which would get the current options, merged in the new ones and then run `setOptions`. But [there is no clean way to get the google.maps.Map options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3369842/684229)!

This really seem to suck... this really tempts me to refrain to [direct object modification as I asked in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9836185/684229), but that could be dangerous, right? But it's really hard to program in a clean way with Google maps api v3!!

Any solutions, thoughts, workarounds?

Comment: I'd write an abstraction which accepts the same object notation as setOptions, and have that abstraction call setOptions with the object in the abstraction. Easy. Have the modules call that abstraction method rather than map.setOptions(). AS well, setOptions by the documentation "creates a map." This itself may have implications down the road regarding persistence. In any case, having all those modules talk directly to Google maps seems like a bad idea in the long run. If you were to move to leaflet or something later, a layer between will make life a lot easier.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is have my maps options stored somewhere where I could retrieve them and changed them as needed before setting them back. You could either use a global JS variable of local storage for that purpose. For instance:

```
var myOptions = { zoom : 12};
map.setOptions(myOptions);
...
myOptions.mapTypeControlOptions = {
                        mapTypeIds: [
                                google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                                google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
                                google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
                                google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
                                'OSM',
                                'OCM'
                        ]};
map.setOptions(myOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, Google Maps options are not getting preserved in that case. But you could consider the following *workaround* .

Even though  `google.maps.Map class` does not expose accessor for [`MapTypeControlOptions` property](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeControlOptions) you could still access it (and therefore modify it) using the below approach:

```
var options = map.mapTypeControlOptions;  //undocumented
```

The below example demonstrates how to preserve Google Maps options:

```js
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: { lat: -28.643387, lng: 153.612224 },
        mapTypeControl: true
    });

    printInfo('Settting map type control options...')
    setMapTypeControlOptions(map);

    var before = JSON.stringify(map.mapTypeControlOptions);
    printInfo('Before:' + before);


    printInfo('Setting map type control options position..');
    setMapTypeControlOptionsPosition(map,google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT);

    var after = JSON.stringify(map.mapTypeControlOptions);
    printInfo('After:' + after);
}


function setMapTypeControlOptions(map) {
    map.setOptions({
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: [
                    google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
                    google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
                    google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            ]
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
    });

}


function setMapTypeControlOptionsPosition(map,value){
    /*map.setOptions({
        mapTypeControlOptions:
           { position: value }
    });*/
    var options = map.mapTypeControlOptions;
    options.position =  value;
}


function printInfo(s){
    //console.log(s);
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += s + '<br/>';
}
```

```css
 html, body {
            height: 220px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map {
            height: 220px;
        }
```

```html
 <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=false&callback=initMap" async defer>
    </script>
<div id='output'/>
```